# pair-distance between collections of data with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list `samples` of L arrays of shape N by 3 representing three dimensional points in space. I want to compute pair-wise distance matrices between every couple i,j of arrays in the list. What I am doing at the moment is simply to loop over the couples i and j and use `cdist`

```
for i in xrange(L-1):
    for j in xrange(i+1,L):
        dists=cdist(sample[i],sample[j])
```

I then use the obtained distance matrix to perform further operations.

Is there a way to avoid the double loop? Maybe through `einsum` over a suitable N by 3 by L array?

Comment: What are typical values for `L` and `N`in your actual use case?

Comment: N=10000 while L~200

Comment: So, you want to avoid the double loop and store all the distances in one big array? If so, that would be a really huge one with a shape of `(19900, 10000, 10000 )`. Are you sure, you want that big array?

Comment: why dont you simply:  scipy.spatial.distance.pdist() ?

Comment: @NikolasRieble  Because `sample[i]` and `sample[j]` would be two different arrays, as `sample` is a list of arrays.

Comment: Hmm, I think @Diavakar is right. What I truly want is actuallly to measure whether two arrays are close enough, so I actually perform a sum np.sum(dists<a). Maybe this changes the scenario and make einsum applicable?

Comment: If you are trying to find the closeness, is that for all rows in `sample[i]` against **corresponding** rows in `sample[j]`? If so, we can avoid `cdist` for performance. But with `cdist`, you are getting the distances for all rows in  `sample[i]` against **all** rows in `sample[j]`, for which `einsum` if applicable won't be efficient.

Comment: Also, have a look here - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html

Comment: Indeed, I need to check against all rows (any potential overlap..). I will have a look at scikit, thank you.